# Crashlytics iOS: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS"

Tags: ios

I got a crashed log from Crashlytics.

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
>   0x000000000000000c
>
> WSConnect.m line 270
>   -[WSConnect webSocket:didReceiveMessage:]

Here's the code cause crashes:

```
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)_webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message{

NSData *data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
MutableOrderedDictionary* dictResponse = [MutableOrderedDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];

NSString* hId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"h%@",mID];
if ([dictRequest objectForKey:hId]) {
    WSPacket* packet = [dictRequest objectForKey:hId];
    @synchronized(@"RemoveLock") {
        [dictRequest removeObjectForKey:hId];
        @synchronized(@"LOCK_PROCESS") {
            packet.handler(dictResponse); // This line made crashed
        }
        packet.handler = nil;
        packet.data = nil;
        packet.mID = nil;
        packet = nil;
    }
    return;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks for reading my issue!

Comment: Hey.. were you able to solve this crash?